# Monitoring executing file

Tags: c, monitoring, performance

I'm doing some research to find out if it is at all possible to monitor an executing application to be able to list the function calls that are made by this application ?

The application is open source and I have identified a few functions that I would like to monitor. I need to do it without modifying the source(to be able to use the monitor on production system).

Is this possible?

I suppose this is OS specific - I would like to do it on Windows and Linux.

Comment: For Linux check the [`ptrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) system call.

Comment: Briefly looking at ptrace - it requires to use fork instead of being able to monitor any other process. Am I right or there's something more about it?

Comment: Search for the `PTRACE_ATTACH` option.

Comment: For windows, you can use process monitor from sysinternals.